# Cannot send email via postfix / dovecot error status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, dovecot, mailx

I am trying to setup a mail server with postfix/dovecot/maria DB on centos 7 and have seem to hit a roadblock.

I am not able to send emails to internal users and the logs suggest "mail transport unavailable". I checked few resources online and dont seem to find help, the services are up and running.

/var/log/maillog

```
Mar  9 21:30:41 server postfix/qmgr[4953]: 2222637E93F: from=<root@server.website-internal.com>, size=472, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  9 21:30:41 server postfix/qmgr[4953]: warning: connect to transport private/dovecot: No such file or directory
Mar  9 21:30:41 server postfix/error[4991]: 2222637E93F: to=<vmail@website-internal.com>, relay=none, delay=0.14, delays=0.09/0.03/0/0.02, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Mar  9 21:34:53 server postfix/pickup[4952]: 59F6E2D66A4: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar  9 21:34:53 server postfix/cleanup[5145]: 59F6E2D66A4: message-id=<20170310053453.59F6E2D66A4@server.website-internal.com>
Mar  9 21:34:53 server postfix/qmgr[4953]: 59F6E2D66A4: from=<root@server.website-internal.com>, size=472, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  9 21:34:53 server postfix/qmgr[4953]: warning: connect to transport private/dovecot: No such file or directory
Mar  9 21:34:53 server postfix/error[5153]: 59F6E2D66A4: to=<vmail@website-internal.com>, relay=none, delay=0.17, delays=0.12/0.03/0/0.03, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Mar  9 21:35:22 server postfix/qmgr[4953]: C47911FB57A: from=<root@server.website-internal.com>, size=476, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  9 21:35:22 server postfix/error[5153]: C47911FB57A: to=<vmail@website-internal.com>, relay=none, delay=540, delays=540/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

I need to find out the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd `strace` the `qmgr` process and hopefully see where the error is coming from.

Is dovecot running?
Does `website-internal.com` have a MX record?

What happens when you run:

```
echo "test" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -fuser@website-internal.com user@website-internal.com
```

Comment: Thanks Ed for replying back. 

Strace qmgr yields nothing 
`[root@server ~]# strace qmgr
strace: Can't stat 'qmgr': No such file or directory`

Dovecot is running (Confirmed). I have 'website-internal.com' running on apache and have enteries for the same in my /etc/hosts, no MX records created on external DNS.

`[root@server ~]# echo "test" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -fuser@website-internal.com vmail@website-internal.com
[root@server ~]#`